# Hibernate is not creating auto table in MySQL

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have looked for answers on this platform and tried but those didn't work for me. If anyone knows any other possible ways to resolve this issue please let me know.

Appreciate your quick response.

Thanks.

[image: Passenger Entity Class]

[image: Passenger Entity Class]

[image: PassengerRepository Interface]

[image: Application Class]

[image: application propeties]

[image: Expected output]

[image: Console message]

[image: my ouput]

[image]

Comment: If the table is not created what is presented on next-to-last pic?

Comment: Also try to turn DEBUG level for logging for get more info

Comment: It's not creating a table and not throwing any errors.

Comment: That is the whole output I have got.

Comment: `mysql >desc passegers` - this output the  table. Isn't it?

Comment: I have added a screenshot that is the output I am getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230414/discussion-between-naresh-and-andrey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not scanning the right package for entities.

```
@EntityScan("com.project.data.entity")
```

Comment: I think I don't need to specify that @EntityScan annotation and I have tried with and without annotation but still, it's not working.

Comment: Thanks, Madlemon it's working for me now. Appreciate it